# Capture events from staging to ensure only events which are NOT cancelled and update existing

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Given that I have a staging table that is incrementally populated daily and keeps track of events where the following scenarios occur:

1. **Created-** Event_UUID is created
2. **Canceled-** If the event is canceled, the event_UUID associated with the cancellation will be the same event_UUID from when the event was created.
3. **Rescheduled-** Upon an event being rescheduled, the old event is canceled and a new event is created; this will generate a new event_UUID but there will be an old_event_uuid which have the details of the old event.

Given the following sample data: 
[image]

How would I create a table which loads from staging on a daily basis but only keeps the events which are "created"/"active" and NOT canceled?

What would the sql script look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try to select only the most recent row for every UUID and discard all of them, that have type canceled:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM staging s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM staging s2 WHERE s2.event_uuid = s.event_uuid AND s2.time > s.time)
    AND s.event_type = 'event.created' -- alternatively: s.event_type <> 'event.canceled'
```

Comment: Given that the staging will simply grow day by day....is there a way to ensure for the Inital load it looks at the entire table..but on a daily run it only looks at peraphs the list time the event itself was created. 

Also What happens if the next day, the event is canceled? Would I be updating the record in my final table or deleting it? Not sure what the best practice should be.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to use one table for your events and another for the (historized) status of the events?
So you can also save a status "done" if the work is done for the event.

If you want to find just events in a specific time span, use ```s.time BETWEEN a AND B```

Comment: Thanks. If I am understanding this correctly, there is nowhere where you are making the association to the old event. Does that mean you are NOT accounting for scenario #3 since you are only ever looking at event_uuid and not the old_event_uuid

Comment: something seems to be missing here.

Comment: Since a reschedule is also a cancel on the old event, the old event will be in state "event.canceled" and thus won't appear. As long as the new event is active, it will appear, no matter if there is an old_event_uuid or not. So there is no need to look for this (at least not for this task). The active status of events does not depend on their possible "ancestors".

Comment: Okay...sorry I'm still a little confused. What would the Load, Inital Load and Incremental Load look like...in terms of Insert Statement, Update Statement and Delete (if applicable)??

Comment: What are you confused about? The concept is unclear? My "historized status concept" comes w/o any updates (there may remain your update in the rescheduling) or deletes. And every time you change the status of an event, you need one insert. For the first state (created) you may also omit the entry (thus every event w/o a state is in state "created", no need to save the time twice). Searching the active events will need to combine every event with its most recent status (if there is one) and filtering by this status afterwards. Thus still every event is looked at.